# Getting Google the number of hits for term search in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the number of results from google for search term in Java.
eg. For the term "computer" :About 3,070,000,000 results.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with Java sample library for custom google search API.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#CustomSearch_API

Also you can reduce the data transferred during service requests by specifying members that contain data elements that your application needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer..but I'm actually searching about the accuracy of results returned by Google.

Comment: Please edit the question and provide details about what do you mean by 'accuracy' (since the total number of results by Google may change even when you are browsing through those pages). Also please provide details how it is related to java.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I meant the accuracy of the hits returned by the API, i used the Google ajax search API and it returns a different number of results from the Google page (hits in the top).

Answer (score 0):

It is not as straightforward as one might think... You can write a Java program that reads the results of a Google search on a term like "computer", but the number of results will not be statically present in the output.

You will have to use the [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/) Engine, or the [JSON/Atom Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm actually searching about the accuracy of results!!?

Comment: Why didn't you ask whether Google result figures are accurate or not then? Also this Q has not much to do with Java you could be searching for "pumpkin". It would probably be better to remove the "java" tag... Anyway, even if the results were accurate they would be accurate for a too short period of time since the Web universe is in constant change...